# Running a shell command from gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I would like to run a shell command from gulp, using `gulp-shell`. I see the following idiom being used the gulpfile.

Is this the idiomatic way to run a command from a gulp task?

```
var cmd = 'ls';
gulp.src('', {read: false})
    .pipe(shell(cmd, {quiet: true}))
    .on('error', function (err) {
       gutil.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`gulp-shell` has been blacklisted. You should use [gulp-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec) instead, which has also a better documentation.

For your case it actually states:

> Note: If you just want to run a command, just run the command, don't use this plugin:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('task', function (cb) {
  exec('ping localhost', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
})
```

Comment: `gulp-shell has been blacklisted`: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Gulp features a blacklist of packages that aren't written in "the Gulp way". Check out the list here: https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json

Comment: The function passed to `exec` doesn't log anything to Gulp. Why isn't that happening?

Comment: what did you mean in your answer "just run the command".. how can I run a command through a gulp task without such a plugin? (must be a task because gulp.watch is calling it on every file change

Comment: Task: Yes. Plugin: No. You don't have to run gulp plugins inside a gulp task. See the task definition below my Note. This is everything you need.

Comment: Update: Still doesn't log anything.

Comment: @Arcrammer got the same issue as you

Comment: You can't use plain 'child_process' exec() with src().  So if you'd like to use pipe(), you may still need this plugin.

Comment: I can't see how gulp-exec's documentation is better... Is there some place I'm not finding?

Comment: Is there a way to automatically "flag" blacklisted plugins?

Comment: @jchook try this: https://gist.github.com/ddprrt/6178d3ce2ae66f97c3689622c4834bdd (untested)

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk Try [exec-chainable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec-chainable)

Answer (score 44):

The new way to do this that keeps console output the same (e.g., with colors):

see: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp.task('my-task', function (cb) {
  var cmd = spawn('cmd', ['arg1', 'agr2'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
  cmd.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('my-task exited with code ' + code);
    cb(code);
  });
});
```

Comment: But be careful if you are on Windows, as spawn() doesn't work reliably, see [this Node issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2318)

Comment: This is the best answer imo +1

Comment: this solution doesn't work for me on windows, but found another one here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841902/how-to-run-ng-build-from-gulp-using-child-process-spawn-or-disable-all-output-in

Comment: Excellent answer! I found & created a more verbose method (https://gist.github.com/rmckeel/b4e60922f5098ced9c50bdd96731b34a/ccca5069825096cb286c46c090312f1b5e0d5594), but I updated that code sample with this inherit stdio concept (https://gist.github.com/rmckeel/b4e60922f5098ced9c50bdd96731b34a), because it is elegant and should work for most purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

With [gulp 4](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/4.0) your tasks can directly return a child process to signal task completion:

```
'use strict';

var cp = require('child_process');
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('reset', function() {
  return cp.execFile('git checkout -- .');
});
```

[gulp-v4-running-shell-commands.md](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-shell-commands.md)

Comment: Gulp 4 is the modern incarnation of Zeno's Paradox.

Comment: Newer Gulp versions don't use `gulp.task` like this. If it doesn't work for you, try `cp.exec` instead of `cp.execFile`

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do this:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('list', function() {
    const cmd = spawn('ls');
    cmd.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });
    return cmd;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Gulp's documentation, you can run a command like `echo` like this:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

function childProcessTask() {
  return cp.exec('echo *.js');
}

exports.default = childProcessTask;
```

`exec` takes one string that will be parsed by the shell, and it silences output by default.

I personally like using `child_process.spawn` instead. `spawn` takes the name of the command, and then a list of arguments. If you use the option `stdio: 'inherit'` it won't swallow its output.

```
function childProcessTask() {
  return cp.spawn('echo', ['one', 'two'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
}
```

### References:

- Gulp documentation: [Returning a child process](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion/#returning-a-child-process)
- Node documentation: [`child_process.exec(command, options, callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)
- Node documentation: [`child_process.spawn(command, args, options)`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)