# Run a npm script from gulp task

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, tsc

How to run a npm script command from inside a gulp task?

package.json

```
"scripts": 
{
    "tsc": "tsc -w"
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('compile:app', function(){
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(/*npm run tsc*/)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

I want to do this because running `npm run tsc` does not give me any error but if I use `gulp-typescript` to compile `.ts` then I get bunch of errors.

Comment: Have you tried this plugin?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell

...`.pipe(shell('npm run tsc'))`...

Comment: You'll lose [incremental compilation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript#incremental-compilation) if you do that though

Comment: @RGraham I am not clear on the benefits either.

Comment: "_gulp-shell has been blacklisted (by Gulp)_" quoting the answer from BrunoLM (see its answer and comment by toszter)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the equivalent using [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

  var result = tsProject.src().pipe(ts(tsProject));

  return result.js.pipe(gulp.dest('release'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['default'], function() {
  gulp.watch('src/*.ts', ['default']);
});
```

Then on your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "gulp": "gulp",
  "gulp-watch": "gulp watch"
}
```

Then run

```
npm run gulp-watch
```

---

<s>Alternatively using [shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell)</s>

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(shell('npm run tsc'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

`gulp-shell` has been [blacklisted you can see why here](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json#L15)

Another alternative would be setting up `webpack`.

Comment: How can i run gulp watch along with npm start. I tried but on npm start the scss is not getting compiled to css as it should be. Here is the code in package.json: "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"gulp\" ",

Comment: Running the command from the command line works fine. Using this I get `ReferenceError: connect is not defined` but even after installing `gulp-connect`, I got events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn npm run buildng ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
Process terminated with code 1.

Comment: Note that `gulp-shell` has been blacklisted by `gulp`. Use `child_process.exec` or `child_process.spawn` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511491/running-a-shell-command-from-gulp

Answer (score 15):

Wasted about 1 hour on this simple thing, looking for a ~complete answer, so adding another here:

If you question is only on typescript (tsc), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36633318/984471
Else, see below for a generic answer.

The question title is generic, so a generic example is given below first, then the answer.

**Generic example:**

1. Install nodejs, if you haven't, preferably LTS version, from here: https://nodejs.org/
2. Install below:

   `npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-run`
3. File `package.json` has below contents (other contents can be there):

```json
{
      "name": "myproject",
      "scripts": {
          "cmd1": "echo \"yay! cmd1 command is run.\" && exit 1",
      }
}
```

3. Create a file `gulpfile.js` with below contents:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var run = require('gulp-run');

gulp.task('mywatchtask1', function () {
    // watch for javascript file (*.js) changes, in current directory (./)
    gulp.watch('./*.js', function () {

        // run an npm command called `test`, when above js file changes
        return run('npm run cmd1').exec();

        // uncomment below, and comment above, if you have problems
        // return run('echo Hello World').exec();
    });
});
```

4. Run the task `mywatchtask1` using `gulp`?

   `gulp mywatchtask1`

Now, gulp is its watching for js file changes in the current directory
if any changes happen then the npm command `cmd1` is run, it will print `yay! cmd1 command is run.` everytime the one of the js file changes.

**For this question:** as another example:

a) `package.json` will have

```
"tsc": "tsc -w",
```

instead of the below:

```
"cmd1": "echo \"yay! cmd1 command is run.\" && exit 1",
```

b) and, `gulpfile.js` will have:

```
return run('npm run tsc').exec();
```

instead of below:

```
return run('npm run cmd1').exec();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

You can try to implement it using childprecess node package or

use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-run

```
var run = require('gulp-run');
gulp.task('compile:app', function(){
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*.js','src/**/*.map'])
    .pipe(run('npm run tsc'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());

});
```

Comment: https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell check this , this may work with latest node versions

Comment: "_gulp-shell has been blacklisted (by Gulp)_" quoting the other answer from BrunoLM (see its answer and comment by toszter)