# Call "ng build" from inside a gulp task

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli in my project.I want to add some gulp tasks for deployment. Is it possible for me to call "ng build" from inside a gulp task ?

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working? It didn't work for me, even with child_process like the answer suggests.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can use child_process to make a command line call:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('build', function (cb) {
  exec('ng build', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
})
```

see also here: [Running a shell command from gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511491/running-a-shell-command-from-gulp) for other solutions.

Comment: Don't forget to navigate to project folder (if your **gulpfile** isn't in the same folder): `exec('cd ./../client && ng build', function(...`